# Android Auto DHU - Waiting for phone

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm trying to run desktop head unit on my pc. I set up everything exactly as this guide specifies: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing, (tried both 2.0 and 1.1 with the same result). It appears to connect correctly, but I can't get it do display anything other than "Waiting for phone". Console displays following:

```
Android Auto - Desktop Head Unit
  Build: 2020-09-20-332761970
  Version: 2.0-windows-beta

[W]: No configuration specified - using default values.
[E]: Could not load configuration from 'C:\Users\kkowalczyk\.android\headunit.ini'.
BoringSSL is the SSL implementation used in the receiver-lib.
Starting link. Requested protocol version: 1.6 (snapshot 314970161)
[I]: Connecting over ADB to localhost:5277...
[I]: connected.
> Phone reported protocol version 1.6
ssl state=TLS client read_server_hello -1
ssl state=TLS client process_change_cipher_spec -1
ssl state=SSL negotiation finished successfully 1
SSL version=TLSv1.2 Cipher name=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Verify returned: ok
```

I'm trying to connect to Pixel 5 (with most recent update), is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I also saw the same issue but resolve by following below steps:

1. Close the DHU emulator.
2. In the AA app, stop the HU server. Wait for a couple of seconds, start the HU server.
3. Stop the HU server again. Wait for a couple of seconds, start the HU server.
4. Start the DHU emulator.
5. The OOBE screen shows up on the AA app in phone. Complete the flow. While you are completing the flow, the emulator will be on the 'waiting for phone' screen.
6. Stop and start the emulator. It will start with the black screen with 'waiting for phone' message but after 2-3 seconds the emulator screen comes up.

Hope it can resolve your issue too.

Comment: Unfortunately this changes nothing, phone still shows that it's connected to car and DHU prints "Verify returned: ok" in console but actual window is endlessly "Waiting for phone"

Comment: I had to repeat the steps 1-4 a couple of times before the screen from step 5 showed up, but it finally worked after that

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue (stuck on the "Waiting for phone..." screen) and was able to fix it by changing **Application Mode** to **Developer** on the Developer Settings screen of Android Auto.

Make sure to restart the head unit server on the phone after that in case it was already running, then reconnect/restart `desktop-head-unit`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues initially and for me the issue was that the "Accept terms" screen of the Android Auto App running on the device that is triggered on connecting to the Emulated HUD was not visible and noticed until I scanned through the recent apps in the Task Switcher.

This is mentioned in step 11  of the *Test Android apps for cars - DHU setup instructions* [here](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#running-dhu)

> If this is the first time you are connecting the mobile device to the DHU, check the mobile device's screen to accept the terms of service and adjust permission settings as needed.

So just note that this screen may not be immediately visible to you unless you switch the relevant screen from the Task Switcher.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test your phone on a real car to make sure phone actually works with Android Auto. I have two phones (Huawei p20 and Xiaomi Mi10): xiaomi works fine but p20 doesn't work with multiple settings and/or option neither in car or DHU, however both of them are considered as compatible with Android Auto.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolved this issue by invalidating cache and restarting android studio. Then I had to restart AA app. After that, it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my "Waiting for phone" endless loop by realizing there is a desktop DHU server ***and*** a DHU server on the android that I didn't initially turn on. Found in `Android Auto Settings > Start Head Unit Server` which is not found in the Developer settings subsection